# Getting UIDNumbers out of AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the UIDNumbers out of all my AD users and after that determining the highest UIDNumber with the following code

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -property UIDNumber | Select-Object UIDNumber | measure -maximum
```

This results in the following:

Count    : 1867
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :

Weird since i don't get the right value in "Maximum" a lot of values are empty as well fyi.

Comment: Since you are passing an object into `Measure-Object`, you need to use `-Property UIDNumber`.

Comment: And the [`uidNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-uidnumber) attribute is an optional attribute, so you can't expect it to always have a value unless you are populating it yourself.

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue i edited the code above

Comment: @GabrielLuci we are populating it partly so do i need to add something to remove the empty records for it to work?

Comment: the `-property` parameter needs to go onto `Measure-Object`

Comment: @claeys You can use the `-Filter` parameter for that, like in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing an object rather than a scalar into `Measure-Object`, you need to pick the property that you want to measure with the `-Property` parameter.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "UIDNumber -like '*'" -Property UIDNumber |
    Measure-Object -Maximum -Property UIDNumber
```

`Select-Object` is not necessary since the `Get-ADUser -Property UIDNumber` returns objects that already contain `UIDNumber`. However, if you use the `-ExpandProperty UIDNumber` parameter of `Select-Object`, you do not need to specify `-Property` in `Measure-Object`.